# How to successfully loop in the middle of a promise chain

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm putting together a promise chain, new to this so apologies. What I want to do is, for any errors in any particular function, I want to wait a second and try again until it succeeds, then continue with the promise chain as per the original plan.

I tried an if statement that called the function again if there was an error message and resolved if there was not, but this would not continue with the promise chain on a success.

I then worked a solution that included a for loop built into the function, as below:

```
var firstMethod = function() {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
       setTimeout(function() {
          console.log('first method completed');
          resolve();
       }, 1000);
    });
    return promise;
 };

var secondMethod = function(someStuff) {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        for(let randomNumber ; randomNumber < .9||randomNumber == null ;  )
            {   
                setTimeout(function() {
                    randomNumber = Math.random();
                    console.log('the number wasn\'t big enough');
                    if (randomNumber>.9)
                    {  
                        console.log("got a number big enough");
                        resolve();
                    }
                }, 1000)
            }
        });
    return promise;
};

var thirdMethod = function(someStuff) {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
       setTimeout(function() {
          console.log('third method completed');
          resolve();
       }, 1000);
    });
    return promise;
 };

 firstMethod()
    .then(secondMethod)
    .then(thirdMethod);
```

It completes firstMethod and then hangs when I try to run it. If I comment out the setTimeout in the secondMethod it works, but I feel this is not emulating the real case scenario I want to use this for.

Where am I going wrong? Is there a better way to loop mid promise chain until you achieve a particular result, then continue with the promise chain?

Comment: The for loop will run forever. What about `setTimeout(resolve, 10000 * Math.random())` ?

Comment: Asynchronous "looping" always requires recursion. Your `for` loop runs immediately.

Comment: The easiest solution is to use `async`/`await` syntax with a simple loop. Make a promise for the `setTimeout` only - never put any logic inside the `new Promise` callback!

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the **secondMethod** with

```
var secondMethod = function (someStuff) {
    var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let randomNumber;
        (function doItUntilGetEnoughBigNumber() {
            setTimeout(function () {
                randomNumber = Math.random();

                if (randomNumber > .9) {
                    console.log("got a number big enough", randomNumber);
                    resolve();
                } else { // edited: message moved her  
                    console.log('the number wasn\'t big enough', randomNumber);
                    doItUntilGetEnoughBigNumber();
                }
            }, 1000)
        })()
    });
    return promise;
};
```

The reason your code doesn't work, because the condition to stop `for` loop is in asynchronous, so it will be deferred, so the `for` loop will go forever.

**Update** Without using [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

```
var secondMethod = function (someStuff) {
    var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let randomNumber;
        function doItUntilGetEnoughBigNumber() {
            setTimeout(function () {
                randomNumber = Math.random();
                if (randomNumber > .9) {
                    console.log("got a number big enough", randomNumber);
                    resolve();
                } else {
                    console.log('the number wasn\'t big enough', randomNumber);
                    doItUntilGetEnoughBigNumber();
                }
            }, 1000)
        }
        doItUntilGetEnoughBigNumber();
    });
    return promise;
};
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks so much. :)
A followup question, if I can: you include the doItUntilGetEnoughBigNumber function inside brackets, and have open/close brackets after the function. I'm not used to this syntax, it looked redundant to me, but sure enough if I removed them it all broke. What function are they serving?

Comment: You are welcome! 
This is called IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE of course you can do without by removing the parentheses and calling the function explicitly.

Comment: I added new version without using IIFE

Answer (score 0):

The important thing about async events (e.g. when setTimeout finishes) is that the handler is not called directly, but the event is put into the so called event queue. The javascript engine (the event loop) takes one event after another out of it and executes it, when its done it takes the next one. At first it will execute your for loop and set all the timeouts. Then when its done and one second passed it will start executing the setTimeout handlers. But as your for loop is infinite, it will never reach this step.

---

The easiest would be to use the `async` syntax:

```
  const timer = ms => start => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

  async function loop(){
    while(true){
      await timer(1000)();
      if(Math.random() > 0.9) return;
   }
 }

 timer(1000)()
    .then(loop)
    .then(timer(1000))
    .then(() => console.log("done"));
```

Alternatively you could use a recursive async function:

```
async function loop(){
  await timer(1000)();
  if(Math.random() > 0.9)
     return true;
  else
     return loop();
}
```